# Which usage is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, british-english

I am preparing a list of my RGB Keyboard Product's features. In a list of features do I need to write sentences starting with *You can*?

> 1. You can change the colors from the app on the phone by connecting via Bluetooth.
> 2. You can also change the colors with the RGB remote controller.

Can I omit *You can*?

> 1. Change the colors from the app on the phone by connecting via Bluetooth.
> 2. Change the colors with the RGB remote controller.

Comment: I am American so this is from the American English perspective.

I would write:

1 - Change the colors using the app on your phone by connecting via Bluetooth.
2 - Change the colors using the RGB remote controller.

Saying "from" here is a bit ambiguous to me, as if the light is emitting from your phone or from the controller itself.

Comment: I've edited to make this a specific question and not an off topic proofreading request.

Comment: I would move that part out of the sentences anyway: You can change colors with 1) the phone app and bluetooth, or 2) the RGB remote control.

Answer (score 1):

A "list" doesn't have to be full sentences, and it is normal to write sentence fragments. You could embed your list in a paragraph with "You can".

> Our keyboard has many features.  You can
>
> 1. Change the color with an app
> 2. ...

But if you do this you should make sure that all the sentences can start "You can..."

By the way, saying "the phone" seems like you provide a phone with the keyboard (a very generous offer)  Perhaps "your phone" would be better.